# Retrieve the first and second value from the map

Tags: java, hashmap

What's the best way to get the first value and second value from the map. 
I am trying to read the `tableLists` map and get the `first and second value` from the map.

Below is the code I have in which `ReadTableConnectionInfo` is the class.

```
private final LinkedHashMap<String, ReadTableConnectionInfo> tableLists;

ReadTableConnectionInfo table = tablePicker();


private ReadTableConnectionInfo tablePicker() {

    Random r = new SecureRandom();
    ReadTableConnectionInfo table;

    if (r.nextFloat() < Read.percentageTable / 100) {
        table = get first value from tableLists map
    } else {
        table = get second value from tableLists map
    }

    return table;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 1st and 2nd, in what order?

Comment: I modified my question, sorry it's a linkedhashmap. So I need first and second value in the way it is inserted in that.

Comment: The order of elements are not guaranteed in a HashMap

Comment: Yup. I modified my question to include LinkedHashMap. Sorry about that

Comment: Did you try the values() method?  It returns a Collection of the values.  But I don't see anything in the Javadoc saying that it'll reflect the order of the backing LinkedList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are sure that your LinkedHashMap contains at least two values, you could do:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ReadTableConnectionInfo >> it = tableLists.entrySet().iterator();
if (r.nextFloat() < Read.percentageTable / 100) {
  table = it.next().getValue();
} else { //since you have an else, you have to re-ignore the first value just below
  it.next(); // ignoring the first value
  table = it.next().getValue(); //repeated here in order to get the second value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iteration of LinkedHashMap values is ordered by the insertion order.  So values() is what you need:

```
Iterator it = values().iterator();
Object first = it.next().getValue();
Object second = it.next().getValue();
```